# Vertex displacement shader graph shows unexpected creases at the beginning and end of a gradient texture

Tags: godot, vertex, displacement-mapping

I'm trying to perform a basic vertex displacement by means of a horizontal gradient:

[image: Vertex displacement setup]

I'm using an on-the-fly created plane mesh. Most of this process is clear to me. I'm not understanding where the weird folds at the beginning and the end are coming from and when it should be a smooth transition from beginning to end.

Settings of the texture:

[image]

Comment: What Godot version is this? I see a Flags section under Repeat on mine, but I don't see it on the screenshot.

Comment: @Theraot its the latest Beta of Godot 4 , im running on windows 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with the help of some Redditor i solved it. The problem is that one cant disable repeat on the texture itself, but has to do a round trip via an input param on which the repeat can be disabled:
[image]

Then the gradient texture can be set as a value for the input param on the object which received the shader as material. Also the type has to be set to color - not data