# Godot: how to get rid of color border in linear gradient texture 2d

Tags: godot, vertex

Im trying to use a linear gradient to displace a plane mesh via vertex displacement in the visual shader editor. However the linear gradient always seems to drop back to the start color at just before the end, which throws of my vertex displacement:
[image]

How do i get rid of that?
The [documentation mentions some "ramp"](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_gradient.html#class-gradient) but i couldnt find it anymwhere in the UI

Comment: Do you see wrapping settings anywhere in that inspector panel? Anything with keywords like "wrap" "repeat" "clamp" "mirror"?

Comment: @DMGregory i only see "repeat" which i have set to "Repeat". If i set it to any of the other options like "No Repeat" or "Mirror Repeat", i get what can be seen here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/202525/vertex-displacement-shader-graph-shows-unexpected-creases-at-the-beginning-and-e 

Its a bit frustrating - maybe i should try to do all this in code since the visual shader editor seems somewhat limited at the moment

Comment: I had not paid attention to the fact that you are using `GradientTexture2D` instead of `GradientTexture`. Does `GradientTexture` not work for you?

Comment: @Theraot i only have GradientTexture1D and GradientTexture2D available, i tried both but the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that the gradient repeat cannot be disabled on the gradient itself, which caused the issues I experienced. See [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/203054/167104) for more information.